# How to refresh the table list in linked server?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm trying to edit a stored procedure, but I'm getting the error

> "The OLE DB provider SQLNCI11 for a linked server does not contain the
>   table"

However, the table is present in that DB.

The table I'm trying to add in the procedure is newly created. (After the stored procedure is created)
Should I re-add the linked server or is there a way to refresh the linked server?

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the object as **fully qualified name**

```
[ServerName].[DATABASEName].[schema].[object]
```

Comment: I found the issue, I forgot to check the permissions of user in linked server. Since it's a new table there were no permissions.

Comment: @Pedi Great! then provide your own answer, then accept it

Answer (score 1):

In addition to using the fully qualified name, from the source server you'll have to define permission for the database user. In my case for the particular table alone.

Path: DB->Security->Users
Double click on the appropriate user
Select Securable section and define permission